# What represents an a arrayOfNulls in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new in Kotlin and I want to understand the use of `arrayOfNulls()` method

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Well, as the docs say:

> It returns an array containing the specified elements.

It means, you can create an array with null values depending in the size you specified
For instance,

```
val arrayOfNulls = kotlin.arrayOfNulls<String>(9)
println (arrayOfNulls)
```

The result would be:

> [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: ...and `arrayOfNulls<Something>(x)` in Kotlin is equivalent of `new Something[x]` in Java.

Comment: Just to add to this, note that this way you will get an array of type `Array<String?>`, so every element you get from it will always be nullable. If you'd like an `Array<String>`, you'll have to initialize all of its elements when you create the array.